# why are updated browsers ignoring /etc/hosts when local domain ends with *.dev?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, dns, hosts, firefox-developer-edition

I recently updated my browsers (Firefox Quantum 62.0, Firefox Developer Edition 63.0b7, and Google Chrome 69.0.3497.100) and suddenly all my local development sites could not be found. I searched for a while online for a solution and finally found that now browsers have some problem with `*.dev` domains placed in my `/etc/hosts` file.

By changing the domains to `*.local` everything was back up and running.

What is the problem with using `*.dev` domains that new browsers seem to do as they please, ignoring my `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: Do not use `.DEV` (nor `.LOCAL` in fact) thinking that is a local TLD, it is not. It is a globally registered one, to Google. And they added HSTS Preloading to it, so anyone using a `.dev` domain name locally will be hit by problems, see https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/ (this is not exactly recent). Your computer uses `/etc/hosts` or not for name resolutions depending on how `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is configured. But then applications, like Chrome are free to do whatever else they prefer, and maybe only using the DNS.

Comment: Also, since not really related to programming, your question is offtopic here. It may be better on [su] for example but check the help and tour page to see what is ontopic.

Comment: @patrick i thought that since it was related to setting up my local development environment it wasn't that off topic here. sorry

Comment: Also @Partick is it possible to change any configuration setting in my browsers to alter this default behavior?

Comment: I am no expert on how Chrome does name resolution, you may find switches on that but 1) I would not bet on it (things working at version X, could break again at version X+1) and 2) the real solution is not to use `.dev` to name things internally. How to do it properly? Register any domain name in any TLD you like, using the official registry for that TLD. Then use internally names anchored in it like `foo.int.example.com` or `bar.private.example.com` and so on. You will then be immune to many problems...